# hyper-v machines are crashing with the message "An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used."

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

Formerly working Hyper-v machines are crashing at start with the message  "An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used."
While ubuntu deskop machines are crashing immediately is the DockerDesktopVm running but docker desktop gets an timeout.

Creating a new machine or reinstall the hyper-v feature in windows doesn't help.
Disabling or Enabling Enhanced Session Mode in the hyper-v settings has no effect.

[image: Error message]

Update 1: a windows machine created with "quick create" is running.

Update 2: after upgrading to windows 10 2004 everything works again.

Comment: What is the network and IP setup of the VM? Is IPv6 enabled?

Comment: @music2myear: It was possible to import the vm on a different host machine and there she starts, ip6 is enabled. Disabling or changing the network adapter on the failing machine did not help.